# How to fail gracefully and get notified if screen scraping fails in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, screen-scraping, heroku, nokogiri

I am working on a Rails 3 project that relies heavily on screen scraping to collect data mainly using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).  I'm aggregating essentially all the same data but I'm grabbing it from many difference sources and as time goes on I will be adding more and more.  However I am acutely aware that screen scraping can be notoriously unreliable.

As such I am interested in how other people have handled the problem of verifying the data and then also getting notified if it is failing.

My current plan is as follow.

1. I am going to have validation on my model for most of the fields.  If they fail I won't get bad data into my system.  Although logging this failure in a meaningful way is still a problem.
2. I was thinking of some kind of counter where after so many failures from a particular source I somehow turn it off.  Not sure how to keep track of that.  I guess the only way is to have a field on my Source model that counts it and can be reset.
3. Logging is 800 pound gorilla I'm not sure how to deal with.  I could just do standard writing to logs but if something fails I'd like to store the entire html so I can figure it out.  Also I need to notify myself somehow so I can address the issues.  I thought of maybe just creating a model for all this and storing it in the database.  If I did this I'd probably have to store the html on s3 or something.  I'm running this on heroku so that influences what I can do.
4. Setup begin and rescue blocks around every field.  I was trying to figure out a to code this in a nicer ruby way so I just don't have a page of them but although I do have some fields are just straight up doc.css_at("#whatever") there are quite a number that require various formatting or calculations so I think it makes sense to try to rescue that so I can then log what went wrong.  The other option is to let the exception bubble up and catch it when I try to create the model.

Anyway I'm sure I'm not even thinking of everything but that is why I'm trying to figure out how other people have handled this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team does something similar to this, so here's some ideas:

- we use a really high level begin/rescue transaction to make sure we don't get into weird half loaded states:

> ```
> begin
>   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
>     ...try to load a data source...
>   end
> rescue
>   ...error handling...
> end
> ```

- Email/page yourself when certain errors occur. We use [exception_notifier](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification) but if you're sitting on Heroku the Exceptional plugin also seems like a good option. I've also heard of people having success w/ [hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home)
- Capturing state is VERY important for troubleshooting issues. Something that's worked quite well for us is GMail. Our loaders effectively have two phases:

  1. capture data and send it to our gmail account
  2. log into gmail, download latest data and parse it

The second phase is the complex one, and if it fails a developer can simply log into the gmail account and easily inspect the failed message. This process has some limitations (per email and per mailbox storage limits, two phase pipeline, etc.) and we started out doing it because we had no other option, but it's proven shockingly resilient and convenient. Keep email in mind as a cheap/easy way to store noncritical state. We didn't start out thinking of using it that way and are now really glad we do. Logging into GMail feels better than digging through log files.

- Build a dashboard UI. We have a simple dashboard with a grid of sources by day that [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8gji.png). Each box is colored either red or green based on whether the load for that source on that day succeeded. You can go one step further and set up a monitor on this UI (mon.itor.us or equivalent) that alarms if some error threshold is met.